# How can I delete the odd rows of a table on oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that saves the GPS transmissions from some vehicles. Each 30 seconds the vehicle transmit his position.
Now I need transmissions for each 1 minute.

I was thinking that I could delete each row with odd rownum.
¿How can I delete the odd rows of a table?

Maybe some vehicles are not transmitting each 30 seconds, i want to check this.
¿How can I check if I really have transmission for each 30 seconds?

This is a small part of the table:

```
DET_ID    DATE_TIME              LATI       LONG
--------- ---------------------- ---------- ----------
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.05.09 AM  11.42341   -81.95251
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.05.39 AM  11.42344   -81.92435
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.06.09 AM  11.43567   -81.85355
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.06.39 AM  11.47851   -81.95246
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.07.10 AM  11.45123   -81.63451
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.07.40 AM  11.43451   -81.95351
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.08.10 AM  11.45251   -81.46785
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.08.40 AM  11.45678   -81.95551
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.09.10 AM  11.43451   -81.93241
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.09.40 AM  11.45456   -81.95251
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.10.10 AM  11.42890   -81.95451
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.15.40 AM  11.43451   -81.95351
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.16.10 AM  11.45251   -81.46785
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.16.40 AM  11.45678   -81.95551
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.17.10 AM  11.43451   -81.93241
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.17.40 AM  11.45456   -81.95251
     3412 15-DEC-16 11.18.10 AM  11.42890   -81.95451
```

Update:
With Mt0's query I found that I have several gaps so deleting the odd row numbers is not a good idea.

How can I delete the rows where is more than 1 value in the same minute (and leave just 1 value for each minute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I delete the odd rows of a table?

If you just want to delete those entries that are in the first half of the minute then:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE  ( date_time - TRUNC( date_time, 'MI' ) ) * 24*60*60 < 30;
```

Or, this will delete the rows where there is an earlier entry in the same minute:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY det_id, TRUNC( date_time, 'MI' )
                               ORDER BY date_time ) AS rn
    FROM   your_table
  )
  WHERE rn > 1
);
```

> How can I check if I really have transmission for each 30 seconds?

This will select all the rows which are not between 29 and 31 seconds after the previous row:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE
           WHEN LAG( date_time ) OVER( PARTITION BY det_id ORDER BY date_time ) IS NULL
           THEN 1
           WHEN date_time - LAG( date_time ) OVER( PARTITION BY det_id ORDER BY date_time )
                  BETWEEN 29/(24*60*60) AND 31/(24*60*60)
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS is_within_30_seconds
  FROM   your_table t;
)
WHERE is_within_30_seconds = 0;
```

Comment: wouldn't be simpler with rownum and mod function. ?

Comment: @SrikanthA No - the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column does not work quite as simply as that.

Comment: @SrikanthA Also, the table can have multiple `det_id` values and using `ROWNUM` does not consider partitioning for these values or if there is a gap in results.

Comment: Right, But lets focus  on the OP's  question - It clearly says delete odd data of the table ordered by data_time. So the simple MOD and ROWNUM should do.

Comment: Actually, OP said they had data every 30 seconds but now only needs every 60 seconds and was thinking it could be done by deleting the odd rows.  They also said they may not have data for every 30 seconds and how can they ensure they have data every 30 seconds.  I think just deleting the odd rows will get unexpected results due to the possibility of non-perfect data.  The solutions in this answer address this.

Comment: @MT0 I tried the query to check if I have transmission for each 30 seconds and I got "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER" (there is also an additional semicolon after your table t;)

Comment: @MT0 I changed "BETWEEN 29/(24*60*60) AND 31/(24*60*60)" by "BETWEEN interval '29' second AND interval '31' second" and it worked

Comment: @MT0 I used the second delete sentence and still some remaining registers with a difference of 30 seconds between them. I tried to use the select sentence to delete those register, replacing the select by delete, but I got "ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view". How can I delete the remaining data?

Comment: Thanks @MT0 those queries were really helpful. Is there a way to use the last query to "delete" instead of "select"?

Answer (score 0):

To delete all rows but first in each group you may use `row_number()` function. For example:

```
create table a(n number);
insert into a values(1.1);
insert into a values(1.3);
insert into a values(1.2);
insert into a values(2.1);
insert into a values(2.5);
insert into a values(3.9);
insert into a values(3.9);
insert into a values(5.5);
insert into a values(6.1);
insert into a values(6.3);
commit;

select * from a;
N
1,1
1,3
1,2
2,1
2,5
3,9
3,9
5,5
6,1
6,3

delete from a
 where rowid in (select rowid
                   from (select rowid,
                                n,
                                row_number() over(partition by trunc(n) order by n) rn
                           from a)
                  where rn > 1);


select * from a;
N
1,1
2,1
3,9
5,5
6,1
```

You may find holes in transmission series using generated time sequence

```
with generator as
 (select rownum rn from dual connect by rownum <= 6)
select * from generator left join a on generator.rn = trunc(a.n) where a.n is null order by rn

RN N
4 -
```

Comment: The OP is not trying to delete duplicate rows but is trying to delete alternate rows.

Comment: @MT0 it's not about duplicates. It's about group all rows within 1 minute and leave alive only first one.

Comment: The OP asked "How can I delete the odd rows of a table?"

Comment: Also, the OP's date shows slippage in the time so that sometimes there is 30 seconds and sometimes it is 31 seconds and you will need to account for that when matching with a generator.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this suffice your requirement.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DUP
  (
    DET_ID    NUMBER,
    DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP,
    LATTI     number,
    LONGI      NUMBER
  );

--Insert Values into table

-- This query will just keep only one record for every minute.
    DELETE
    FROM TEST_DUP
    WHERE ROWID IN
      (SELECT a.RID
      FROM
        (SELECT ROWID rid,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DET_ID,TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') ORDER BY 2) RN
        FROM TEST_DUP
        )a
      WHERE a.rn > 1
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this delete sentence deletes almost the entire table and just leaves 1 row for minute not considering the det_id. I am looking for leaving 1 row for minute on each det_id.

Comment: Yes it will as i dint add the DET_ID as a PARTITION clause. Modified the answer Now it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I still having some rows with a difference of less than 1 minute between them. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Could you please post the data which is problematic. Since per the sample data posted, it is working as expected.

Comment: I added some rows to the example. In this case, keeping one record for every minute leaves the row at "11.15.40 AM" at 30 seconds from the next row.